# Django child models don't inherit Meta inner class

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I have two Django 3.0 models, one of which is a subclass of the other:

```
# models.py
class BaseCategory(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

class Category(BaseCategory):

    # fields 'n' stuff
```

Only the `Category` model is registered in the Admin

```
# admin.py
@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # stuff here
```

In the Admin, the `Category` model is labeled "Categorys", despite the fact that it should have inherited the `Meta` inner class and its `verbose_name_plural` attribute from `BaseCategory`.  In fact, if I copy the same code into the `Category` model,

```
# models.py
class Category(BaseCategory):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    # fields 'n' stuff
```

the model is correctly labeled "Categories" in the Admin.  This indicates that the `Category` class is not inheriting the `Meta` inner class of `BaseCategory`.

Why does a child class not inherit the `Meta` inner class?  Is there another way for me to only specify `verbose_name_plural` once instead of copying the exact same code into every child of `BaseCategory`?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance) you need to declare the `BaseCategory` model abstract in order for its Meta class to be inherited.

```
class BaseCategory(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"
```

The `Category` class will then automatically inherit the `Meta` class, except for the `abstract` attribute.

Note that if you want to make any changes to the `Meta` class in `Category` you need to subclass it explicitly:

```
class Category(BaseCategory):

    class Meta(BaseCategory.Meta):
        ...
```

Comment: Where do the docs say that `Meta` isn't inherited for non-abstract classes?  I can't find it.  The section you link to says that `Meta` is made available as an attribute for subclasses of abstract classes, but that has nothing to do with what I'm doing.

Comment: I interpreted the docs to mean that Meta wouldn't be inherited automatically unless the class was abstract. I suppose you could inherit explicitly `class Meta(BaseCategory.Meta)` without making the class abstract. I've never tried it that way. Does your code work if you make `BaseCategory` abstract?

Comment: The default Python inheritance rules would make `Meta` inherited, so if Django breaks that I'd expect a clear statement of that fact independent of anything related to abstract classes.  If I could trust them to document their code competently, at least.  I can't make `BaseCategory` abstract.